# OS Tree Support in artifactory

Tags: artifactory, flatpak

Do you know if there is a way to make artifactory support OSTree? We're currently working on adding flatpak to our software stack and were trying to implement it in Artifactory. With Flatpak using OSTree in mind, has anybody had success in setting up artifactory to work with OSTree?

Looking at artifactory's links, there has been comments on their Jira board with the following but was wanting to see if this was still the case
https://jfrog.atlassian.net/browse/RTFACT-19715

Comment: Artifactory don't support OSTree currently.
There is an open feature request on the subject and it will be decided per demand and product decision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not find Artifactory satisfying, you can turn to Pulp. Pulp supports OCI-based flatpaks (pulp_container, https://docs.pulpproject.org/pulp_container/workflows/flatpak-support.html) as well as OSTree native flatpaks (pulp_ostree).

Pulp is an open-source tool and it is shipped for free. You can try running it in a container to see if it fits your needs: https://pulpproject.org/pulp-in-one-container/. The image contains both pulp_container and pulp_ostree enabled by default.

Here is an overview of Pulp: https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=grDXPtnJu4U.